# Is there any possibility in making a twitter bot without using the dev api?

Tags: twitter, bots

Is there any possibility in making a twitter bot without using the dev api?

I would need a script / bot that can post and auto respond to dms without the twitter dev api is there any way i can do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify as to *why* you'd *want* to do this *without* the API...?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible without the Twitter API.

Comment: I will make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it very possible you can use selenium in python to give the web inte

Answer (score 0):

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
# import pandas as pd

query = "nft"
tweets = []
limit = 10


for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
    
    if len(tweets) == limit:
        break
    else:
        tweets.append([tweet.url])
        
print(tweets)
```

Comment: its just an example and you can get any data using "tweet."